# Adding colored frame around an image at runtime in Android

Tags: android, image, frame

Can I add colored border or frame to an image (not Image View) at run time. If yes, how to do that. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Bitmap someImage;


int width = someImage.getWidth();   
int height = someImage.getHeight();

RectF targetRect = new RectF(3, 3, width - 3, height - 3);

Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + 20, height + 20,someImage.getConfig());

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawBitmap(someImage, null, targetRect, null);
```

Just change the padding and color according to your needs.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a XML for this shape in a drawable folder [get code from here](http://jsfiddle.net/6atZ2/).
2. Set this shape to a relative layout.
3. Create a image view in a Relative Layout and Set a image src at runtime using :

   ```
   ImageView imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement);

   imageViewMyGraphicalImageElement.setImageBitmap(sBitmap);
   ```

Comment: mate....thank you soooo much for this gem buried between all suggestions...i tried almost everything and nothing worked for my case, except this :) i wasted 3 hours trying to achieve having borders around my imageview until found this post

Answer (score 0):

you can use

**`android:background="path"`** to that image as frame which should have only frame border
and center part should be transparent and

your Image should be assigned as

**`androd:src="path"`**....

and also give padding 
i.e.

**`android:padding="3dp"`**
padding may be up to 5dp or it should depend on thickness of your frame border...

so it will look like...

[image]

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activity_test_img_signs"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/imagesize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/imagesize"
            android:background="@drawable/img_border_new"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/q101"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```